# PPTP VPN won't connect after updating to El Capitan

Tags: vpn, macos, pptp

This is a 2015 rMBP and after I updated to El Capitan (have not installed any betas) my PPTP VPN connection just hangs on "Connecting". If I then click "Disconnect" it hangs similarly until I kill pppd.

Anyone have this problem and found a solution?

Edit: system.log after clicking "Connect":

```
Oct 15 19:03:56 nspassov nesessionmanager[5803]: NESMLegacySession[VA:0CABA80E-F475-40F9-B087-AF2C698ADB71]: Received a start command from com.apple.preference.network.re[23190]
Oct 15 19:03:56 nspassov nesessionmanager[5803]: NESMLegacySession[VA:0CABA80E-F475-40F9-B087-AF2C698ADB71]: status changed to connecting
Oct 15 19:03:56 nspassov pppd[23225]: NetworkExtension is the controller
Oct 15 19:03:56 --- last message repeated 1 time ---
Oct 15 19:03:56 nspassov pppd[23225]: password not found in the system keychain
Oct 15 19:03:56 nspassov pppd[23225]: publish_entry SCDSet() failed: Success!
Oct 15 19:03:56 --- last message repeated 1 time ---
Oct 15 19:03:56 nspassov pppd[23225]: pppd 2.4.2 (Apple version 809) started by nick, uid 501
Oct 15 19:04:13 nspassov pppd[23225]: assertion failed: 15A284: libxpc.dylib + 27218 [3E09C275-A33B-357A-B0AB-A2DDF88EC9D5]: 0x13
Oct 15 19:04:13 nspassov pppd[23225]: assertion failed: 15A284: libxpc.dylib + 23599 [3E09C275-A33B-357A-B0AB-A2DDF88EC9D5]: 0x13
Oct 15 19:04:14 --- last message repeated 909 times ---
Oct 15 19:04:14 nspassov com.apple.xpc.launchd[1] (com.apple.screensharing[23227]): Endpoint has been activated through legacy launch(3) APIs. Please switch to XPC or bootstrap_check_in(): com.apple.screensharing.server
Oct 15 19:04:14 nspassov pppd[23225]: assertion failed: 15A284: libxpc.dylib + 23599 [3E09C275-A33B-357A-B0AB-A2DDF88EC9D5]: 0x13
```

Comment: Anything of interest in the log files?

Comment: Added log files from the Console

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With 10.11.1 i can now connect again.